# Jackson circular reference (2.0)

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, circular-reference

I have a user -> hasMany userPermission, and am getting a circular reference when spring MVC tries to output JSON.  If I set the user permissions to null, it works.  If I have a user->hasmany->userpermission (and permission manyToOne user) I get a stack overflow.

User class has:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference("user-perm") private List<UserPermission> userPermissions;
```

UserPermissoin has:
//bi-directional many-to-one association to User

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    @JsonBackReference("user-perm") private User user;
```

Any ideas here?

---

*** Update *** Jackson 2.3.0 fixed it, Spring works with 2.3.0 from 1.9 with no config changes, just changing the maven dependencies.

Comment: can you use ids instead of objects? I mean in the list.

Comment: Well, the whole point is to return the user from a RESTful service to display the permission details.

Comment: in this case convert them to the String

Comment: So, I should have different fields for the JPA  and for Jackson?  The ignore annotation didn't seem to work, either.

Comment: Please enter your own answer rather than proclaim 'solved' in the title.

Answer (score 0):

> > **user1022260**: Jackson 2.3.0 fixed it, Spring works with 2.3.0 from 1.9 with no config changes, just changing the maven dependencies.